# npm install fails after any project downloaded from github

Tags: node.js, github, npm, project

My ubuntu 18.04 machine gives errors whenever I try to run 'npm install'. I guess there are some permission issues. Please Help!

Comment: please provide the full error message

Comment: How do i put the errors here? Is there any log file that I can access?

Comment: Edit your question, then Copy & Paste the message error, select message error make it code block using `Ctrl + K`

Comment: Well I don't know what might've happened. I've upgraded my ubuntu to 20.04 and everything's working.